# Can't install namespace Helm chart

Tags: namespaces, openshift, project, helm3

I'm trying to put together a helm chart for provisioning namespaces/projects in OpenShift.

Helm version is 3.9.3

The templates folder has YAML files for the namespace, compute quota, docker pull secret, and a rolebinding for a service account.

The testvalues.yaml file is very simple:

```
namespace:
  name: "mytest"
  team: "DevOps"
  description: "Test Namespace Created with Helm"
```

When I try to run `helm upgrade --install testnamespace ./namespaceChart --values testvalues.yaml` I get an error "namespaces 'mytest' not found".

However, if I remove the quota, secret, and rolebinding files from the templates directory(leaving only namespace.yaml) and run the same command, it works fine, empty namespace is created.  I then re-add the other resource yaml files, run the same command for a 3rd time, it works and adds the missing resources accordingly.

The order is supposed to create the namespace first, correct?  It seems like its not creating the namespace correctly, or not waiting until it is done before trying the other resources.

I've tried adding the `--create-namespace` option to the command and that doesn't work either.

Is there something I'm missing?  Can I target only the namespace.yaml file on the first round, then just run the command again to complete the rest?

Answer (score 0):

Realized my problem while typing this question up.

My namespace yaml was using:

```
kind: Project
apiVersion: project.openshift.io/v1
```

Because that is what our current project spaces show when I inspect their YAML in the Console UI.

Once I switched to:

```
kind: Namespace
apiVersion: v1
```

Everything gets setup perfectly fine in one shot.  I'm guessing this is because Helm doesn't recognize the "Project" kind as the same as a namespace and doesn't place it at the top of the creation order, thus the "not found" error because it is actually seeing the quota as the first resource to build.